# How to send image tag trough html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am struggling with this line for one hour now, so I decided to ask.

```
$('.tempc').html($('.tempc').html() + '<img src="images/wheather/3.png" width="139" height="50"/></br>');
```

I could not get `html` to inject image tags into `divs`.

```
<div class="tempc"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('.tempc').append($('<img src="images/wheather/3.png" width="139" height="50"/><br/>'));
```

Comment: <img src="images/wheather/3.png" width="139" height="50"></br> output on firebug missing "/"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tempc').html('<img src="images/wheather/3.png" width="139" height="50"/></br>');
```

the difference with append method above, this code will erase all html inside the .tempc and replace with this , while in append, if your .tempc has element inside it, it will not be erased just appended..but i think all you need to use is append..

Comment: Thanx for the note. My question is how to dynamicly(using jquery) insert picture in to div with given class name?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function insert(){

  $('.tempc').append('<img src="http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/340x221p/photos.demandstudios.com/getty/article/203/184/200446250-001.jpg" width="139" height="50"/></br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tempc"></div>
<button onclick='insert()'>Append</button>
```